# Accessing json keys with special characters in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an object which looks like this:

```
{"response":{"mydata":[{"xxx:id":"8c8b9703-bc87-40d8-b8d7-f71ebff4002a","Description":"Tsameple desc"].....
```

Now, my question is, How do I access the Id field?

I have tried

```
$.response.mydata[i].xxx:id
```

However, this is resulting in an error thanks to the ":" in the key value. Any tips on how I can get the value?

Comment: Of course it's a multi-duplicate but I don't find it...

Answer (score 22):

Use the [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Objects_and_properties) :

```
response.mydata[i]['xxx:id']
```