# JSON Parsing w/list and Iteration

Tags: javascript, json

I have a sample JSON document that has data similar to this:
`{"lake-piers": {"Ozark Mountain": [" fish bass", " fish catfish", " fish bluegill", " fish sunfish"],"Small Mountain": [" fish catfish", " fish bluegill", " fish sunfish"]}}`

What I am looking to do is extract the keys (Ozark Mountain and Small Mountain) and the associated lists with each of them. What is throwing me a bit is the lake-piers.  For two reasons.  1) the "-" which I believe i can just do a text.replace with.  The second is to keep it from being the only key with JSON.parse.

Comment: Ad 1) - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24818524/accessing-json-keys-with-special-characters-in-javascript

Comment: _“The second is to keep it from being the only key with JSON.parse”_ - that makes no sense. It **is** the only key on the top-most level.

Comment: Ultimately what I have is this JSON being returned from a nodeJS app.  I intend to display just the list of piers and their associated fish.

Comment: So, access the object on the first level using its key, and then loop over it ...

Comment: Cool thanks.  I think i was having issues with that key notation to your first comment.  Fixed it right up.  Appreciate the help!