# Postman Get response in a variable - Special character

Tags: javascript, json, postman

Taking into account the result of a POST request

```
{
    "<Id>k__Field": "ac12432e-b1fb-4c46-9aed-9d7e246bf613"  
}
```

the special characters "<", ">" come with the response of the request.

I need to get this result in a variable inside Postman:

[image: code]

But it is throwing an error.

How can I get the value in a correct way?

Comment: what s the `<Id>` supposed to be, both logically and syntactically?

Comment: <Id> comes in the response, for some reason the editor was omiting it, I have added blank spaces to clarify

Comment: After the edit this is a duplicate of [Accessing json keys with special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24818524/accessing-json-keys-with-special-characters-in-javascript)

Comment: I don't see the relation with the reference, please clarify

Comment: `<` is a special character. The linked question is an ***exact*** duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you should just omit `Id` altogether as it isn't in the JSON.

`var id = jsonData.k__Field;`

Also `<Id>` is not valid JS syntax

You should use:

```
var id = jsonData["<Id>k__Field"];
```

Comment: this is not correct, <Id>k__Field comes with the response

Comment: Ok. You may want to use square bracket notation.

Comment: var id = jsonData["< Id >k__Field"];

Comment: this is solving the question